# Create module prestashop 1.5

Tags: php, module, e-commerce, prestashop

I created a new module in PrestaShop 1.5 
mau file `mymodule.php` content

```
 <?php
  if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
   exit;
 
  class myModule extends Module
   {
    public function __construct()
     {
      $this->name = 'mymodule';
      $this->tab = 'Test';
      $this->version = 1.0;
      $this->author = 'Firstname Lastname';
      $this->need_instance = 0;
 
      parent::__construct();
 
      $this->displayName = $this->l('My module');
      $this->description = $this->l('Description of my module.');
     }
 
   public function install()
    {
    if (parent::install() == false)
      return false;
    return true;
    }
   public function uninstall()
    {
    if (!parent::uninstall())

    parent::uninstall();
    }
   }
?>
```

But i have an error msg

> mymodule (erreur de syntaxe dans /modules/mymodule/mymodule.php)
>    mymodule (classe manquante dans /modules/mymodule/mymodule.php)

can you help me please

Comment: Please post english error messages on this website (just add a translation so it is clear what that means). Thank you.

Comment: Just a remark: the syntaxe should be "class MyModule extends Module" instead of "class myModule extends Module".

Answer (score 2):

This problem is solved when I change the encoding of page ( Encode in UTF-8 without BOM).

Comment: Could explain better. What page did you do that on?

Answer (score 1):

do you create a config.xml file for that module ?? and one another thing ... there is not 
" Test " tab in prestashop . change that to a valid tab attribute .
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module
this link can help you .

Comment: adding config.xml file worked for me. ( using v1.6 )

Answer (score 0):

I would choose class name to be same as module name.

```
   class mymodule(){
```

not **myModule**

Also you've written

```
  if (!parent::uninstall())
        parent::uninstall();
```

in meaning if uninstall have errors you unninstall by force?
I think, it's better to

```
   if(parent::uninstall())
          return false;
   return true;
```